# Whenever i load a localhost using the firebase serve command it loads older code?

Tags: css, firebase

Whenever i load a localhost using the firebase serve command it loads older code. I dont know how to fix this issue, my new code is in the public folder and still does not function as i wanted it to.

What im trying to: That my new code would be used instead of my older code this is especially with css as it has trouble with loading that.